# What is the command line to schedule a task to be executed once and soon?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I know there is the *[at](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)* and *[schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true)*.
But I couldn't figure out how to use them to execute a task soon and once.
I have read about a *[soon](http://ss64.com/nt/soon.html)* command, but there isn't such command in my Windows version.

I plan to include this command in a batch file and, because of that, I can't hardcode the start time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The schtasks command can run a defined task immediately.

From [How to use Schtasks.exe to Schedule Tasks in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596)

> **Schtasks /Run**
>
> Starts a scheduled task immediately.
>   The run operation ignores the
>   schedule, but uses the program file
>   location, user account, and password
>   that are saved in the task to run the
>   task immediately.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> schtasks /run /tn TaskName [/s computer [/u [domain\]user /p password]] /?
> ```

So just define the task, then run it immediately at any time you need to.

Comment: I just need to know now how to create a scheduled task without a schedule, to use your solution. Otherwise I could risk running it twice.

Comment: You could define a schedule that can never be executed. You might also try /Run of a disabled job - it might work (the documentation doesn't say no).

Answer (score 7):

Working on top of [Keith's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/243252/what-is-the-command-line-to-schedule-a-task-to-be-executed-once-and-soon/243275#243275) to suit your needs:

```
timeout /t X ; psexec -i -s Y
```

Where

1. `timeout` replaces sleep in Windows 7.
2. `X` is the **seconds to wait** defined by `/t`, add `/nobreak` if you want to disallow the user to continue.
3. [**`psexec`** from Microsoft SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) allows you to run interactive (`-i`) **as the local system** (`-s`),
   please note that you have to start psexec once to accept the first time EULA, or add `-accepteula`.
4. `Y` is your command.

`runas` doesn't allow you to start as local system, that's why to use  [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) for process-related tasks.
Starting a Scheduled Task or Service seems like too much of a workaround for me...

---

For example, [Patrick's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/243252/what-is-the-command-line-to-schedule-a-task-to-be-executed-once-and-soon/245136#245136) can simply be rewritten as:

```
timeout /t 120 ; psexec -i -s calc.exe
```

Comment: +1 for **`timeout`**'s simplicity. **`at`** complained on me in Windows 7. And although **`schtasks`** allows you to simply enter the target time (and possibly date) - whereas with `timeout` you have to calculate the number of seconds until that time yourself - when you want to run something at a certain time, you have to first `schtasks /create` it, and later `schtasks /delete` it, otherwise it will linger around. **Why would you want to store global (and permanent) state for a one-off task anyway?** This also forces you to choose a unique name so as not to overwrite some existing task?

Answer (score 3):

This starts calc.exe in 2 minutes. Change the

```
set /A START_MIN=%%j + 2
```

line to change the time interval.

```
for /f "delims=:. tokens=1,2" %%i in ("%time%") do (
set /A START_HOUR=%%i
set /A START_MIN=%%j + 2
)

IF %START_MIN% GEQ 60 (
call :AdjustStartTime
)

IF %START_MIN% LSS 10 SET START_MIN=0%START_MIN%

SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONCE /TN "My Scheduled Task Name" /RU "" /TR "C:\Windows\System32\Calc.exe" /ST %START_HOUR%:%START_MIN%

:AdjustStartTime
SET /A START_HOUR=%START_HOUR% + 1
SET /A START_MIN=%START_MIN% - 60
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `at`, a quick way is to just sleep before your main program.

```
sleep 10 ; mycommand
```

Or put that in a script.

Comment: One of my goals is to execute the command as the LocalSystem user. Your solution doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: @Jader: That's important information you need to state in the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Patrick S.'s answer](https://superuser.com/a/245136/1100) met my needs.

I would like to mention however that the quotation marks do not need to be there following the `/TR` and for whatever reason, seemed to break my script.

Upon removal, his script worked great!

My usage was in an Outlook rule.  A script is called and an email is written to the drive with a plugin (messagesave). This is to post to a website from my office PC for a website and my original script that calls the batch needs to terminate prior to a file being written. I had a tough time figuring out how to appropriately delay the scheduled task, even after hitting the 'schtasks' TechNet page.